# select only specific dates oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got an example query like

```
  select cu.customer_no
  from customers.cu 
  where cu.audit_date like '01-FEB-14'
```

The problem is that I would like to retrieve data only for specific dates which are the first day of the month and skip all of them in between. The desired query should be something like

```
  select cu.customer_no
  from customers.cu 
  where cu.audit_date like ('01-FEB-14', '01-JAN-14', '01-MAY-14')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `audit_date` is a `date`, not a `varchar2`, if you are certain that the time component is always midnight, you can do

```
WHERE cu.audit_date = trunc(cu.audit_date, 'MM')
```

If there may be a non-midnight time component and you want to ignore the time component, you can do

```
WHERE trunc(cu.audit_date) = trunc(cu.audit_date, 'MM')
```

Alternately, you can use `to_char`

```
WHERE to_number( to_char( cu.audit_date, 'DD' ) ) = 1
```

Comment: Ok but how can I select then the last day of the month, not the first?

Comment: @user3017335 - `WHERE trunc(cu.audit_date) = last_day(cu.audit_date)` assuming there may be non-midnight time components that you want to ignore.

Comment: That's great but the thing is that I want to select two different columns whose dates are synchronized in a sense that one of them trunc(cu.audit_date) = trunc(cu.audit_date, 'MM') and based on that the other one should be something like de.date_to = cu.audit_date - 1. In other words select the first day of one of them and the other two should be the first day of the month - 1 to get the last day of the month for the other one?

Comment: @user3017335 - It sounds like you're changing the question rather substantially.  You probably want to create a new question that asks the more specific question you actually have.  I'm not sure that I understand what your new question is, you may want to provide things like sample data and expected output in your new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select cu.customer_no
    from customers.cu 
    where cu.audit_date 
    in  (select distinct trunc(audit_date ,'MM') from customers);
```

Comment: The Subquery will ensure all the starting date